# Our name on SE Data Explorer is Statistical Analysis. Is this by design?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is it on purpose that our name on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) is 'Statistical Analysis' rather than 'Cross Validated'.

[image]

This is not only on the main page, but also when one is inside a query and want to select Cross Validated by clicking in the 'switch sites' check box.

[image]

Comment: I believe it's a vestige from the origins of this site, when four years ago we had not yet voted on a name.  Some of us have been aware of the discrepancy but have kept quiet because "Statistical Analysis" is manifestly a better description than "CrossValidated" :-).

Comment: Even if it is not on purpose, the association that creates is excellent: **"Cross-validated Statistical Analysis"** - what more can we ask for? (given that "cross-validated" may refer not only to a specific technique, but also to a general notion of credible statistical analysis).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official policy of SE is to give all sites the descriptive name and *.stackexchange.com domain because it is good for SEO and SE business overall; there are basically 3 reasons for an exception:

1. being a pre-Area 51 and pre-SE site (StackOverflow, ServerFault and SuperUser),
2. political reasons (MathOverflow, AskUbuntu, +-AskDifferent),
3. issues with a descriptive name or a strong community demand (Seasoned Advice, Mi Yodeya, Arquade and CrossValidated).

In our case, the reason to be in the group 3 is that Statistical Analysis does not cover the whole scope of the site (mainly machine learning, but also visualization and data mining; and it is a real problem what numerous failures of machineLearning.SE have shown), and is on its own a historical artifact because this site was proposed on Area51 as only for statistics and expanded during the private beta period. There was even an idea to change the descriptive name to "Data Stack Exchange" but the data.stackexchange.com have been already taken by the Data Explorer.

Nevertheless, because of the already mentioned SEO stuff and maybe some internal mechanics sites from the group 3 still have *descriptive name*.stackexchange.com domains and use their descriptive name in data dumps and darker places as the data explorer.

Comment: ...and the domain name is not even "statisticalanalysis.stackexchange.com", but "stats.stackexhange.com". The first does not result -it does not redirect to the second.

Answer (score -4):

I think we should change the name to Machine Learning or something.  Do it before the Data Scientist SE site takes the glory:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: What do you mean by "glory"? How would we know that datascience.SE has taken it?

Comment: The glory is being recognized by historians as the first community on this platform to recognize that machine learning is being hampered by current "best" practices of cross-validation.  When we start seeing higher-quality posts on datascience, and/or if they change their name first, we would lose the opportunity.